# Flutter - Publish Privately

Tags: flutter, publish, mobile-development

I am currently working on a mobile app using Flutter.

After finishing the project I would like to make it possible to publish it privately, which means that only specific users who, for example, received a link, are able to use the app.

I know there's already a similar question but I would like to know what's your experience with the topic.

What are the best solutions for this?

Comment: Hey Tamiond, if you are new to StackOverFlow, then you might wanna **mark the answer as correct**, whichever one helped you the most. If you can upvote it, upvote it as well. It helps the other folks to look for the best option by seeing that marked answer, who will looking for this question. :) This way we also, get to know that which answer worked out for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do this that i know of

1. [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution)
2. Internal Test(for android) and TestFlight(for iOS)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if this will work out for you, but it is just a workaround, if the only the `link` is concerned. I know there are lot of things you can do, people will also advice you some best options, but this is something which I have used in my company, to be able to test and get feedback from certain people.

> 1. Publish your app for just in release mode. `flutter clean` will remove the cache, and helps you release the minimal sized app. **After all when we publish we need the apk file only**

```
flutter clean && flutter build apk --release
```

> 2. When you have the `release-apk` with you, just upload it on your `Google Drive` or your private server.
> 3. Get the `sahrable link` from the `Google drive` or `YOUR PRIVATE SERVER`, from where people can download, and then they will be able to test it and your task will be done.

**PLEASE NOTE:** This is just a work around, and can be followed, if you don't want to take too much of headache for just this task, that is `testing and feedback privately`. **I have done this, and it is safe unless everyone has your link, which you won't do :)**

Let me know how this goes for you, and if you have something for me, feel free to suggest. I will learn too :)